# What is the right approach to bucket users for algorithms with different coverage for A/B testing

Tags: experiment-design, recommender-system, ab-test

I've couple of recommendation algorithms that I want to A/B test. Algorithm A has 90% user coverage and algorithm B has 95% user coverage. That means if the algorithms are asked to provide recommendations for 1000 users, algorithm A can give it for 900 of the users and algorithm B can give it for 950 other users. Say for example out of these 1000 users 87% has recommendations from both algorithm, 3% has recommendations from only algorithm A and 8% has recommendations from only algorithm B. What would be the ideal approach to bucket the users

1. Bucket only those 87% users as that can generate even bucketing, but the higher coverage of algorithm B won't reflect in A/B test.
2. Bucket all 95% users, but that could cause uneven bucketing.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you trying to decide determine how to reconcile when the algorithms agree/disagree with one another?

Comment: What is your actual hypothesis of the A/B test, and why splitting your entire user base into two random halves is not feasible/preferred?

Comment: Please can you also clarify why would option 2 cause uneven bucketing?

Comment: I'm trying to find out which algorithm generates better ctr.

Comment: @0xF How are you defining CTR (assumed to be click-through rate) in this case - # click per recommendation item shown? # clicks per user who are eligible/covered by recommendations? # clicks per user in the test? Depending on your business context and needs (e.g. whether non-covered users matter) the splitting approach may drastically vary, and it is best to be clear on that first.

Comment: @B.Liu actually I'd better call that `open rate`. Both of these algo will generate recommendations for the users and the best recommendation will be sent to users as push notification. If the user opens the notification and comes back to app, that would be considered as success. So success/total = open rate that I'd measure here.

Comment: @0xF If you define open rate as (# users who come back)/(# users you send recommendation to) and solely measure on it, by definition you won't be able to capture the effect of algorithm B having a higher coverage. My point here is, before you decide on the bucketing approach, you have to decide what is good (if it is increased open rate for those who get recommendations - i.e. better recommendation quality, or increased open rate for your entire user base - i.e. combination of recommendation quality and coverage), and that remains unclear to me.